# MySQL cannot access field from query within subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to resolve this problem. I have looked through many similar problems posted on here, but I can't find a workaround that works for me.

I have three tables, `ctRequests` holds reservation requests made by each user, `ctBookings` holds details of confirmed reservations, `ctBookingsUsers` links a variable number of users with each confirmed booking.

I need the query to return all *future* requests and cross-reference that with that user's last confirmed reservation *up to but not beyond* the date of the request. The problem I'm having is this statement returns the error "unknown column: 'ctRequests.reqDate' in 'where clause' "

```
SELECT reqID, reqDate, location, startTime, userID, userName, lastBooking
FROM ctRequests
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT userID, MAX(resDate) AS lastBooking 
       FROM ctBookings 
          LEFT JOIN ctBookingsUsers 
          USING(bookingID)
       WHERE resDate <= ctRequests.reqDate
       GROUP BY userID) prevBookings
   USING(userID)
   LEFT JOIN UserNames
   USING(userID)
WHERE reqDate >= NOW() 
ORDER BY reqDate, location, startTime
```

Please can someone suggest how I can resolve this.

**EDIT -**

As requested, sqlFiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13b30b)

Comment: You have listed your 3 tables, but could you also show us your table schemas (columns)? That error comes from the table `ctRequests` not having a column called `reqDate`. Please see "Help others reproduce the problem" on the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The column exists. The same column is in the main SELECT field list and if I replace `ctRequests.reqDate` with a fixed date string the query works fine

Comment: Please edit your question to show all columns for your 3 tables. As I mentioned from the "how to ask" page, saying "the column exists" isn't as useful as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) especially using a service (again, as mentioned in the help article) like http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show us a working example of this error.

Comment: If your MySQL version allows (8.0.14 needed) then use [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html).

Comment: Ah, your subquery is `SELECT ... FROM ctBookings JOIN ctBookingsUsers ...`, so the table `ctRequests` isn't used here. You need to `JOIN` it into this query. I'd start with getting your subquery `SELECT userID, MAX(resDate) AS lastBooking 
       FROM ctBookings 
          LEFT JOIN ctBookingsUsers 
          USING(bookingID)
       WHERE resDate <= ctRequests.reqDate
       GROUP BY userID` to work first, and then include that in the larger query. I'm not seeing a direct relationship between the `ctRequests` and `ctBookings` tables, so that's something you may need to investigate further

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Akina. I tried to follow the example as shown in the page you linked but it is throwing a syntax error. [Any idea what I'm doing wrong?](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCUddhSs8Xtr74tKjoc6YR/0)

Comment: as  WOUNDEDStevenJones says,i alter the subquery  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13b30b/20)

Comment: *Any idea what I'm doing wrong?* You forget to check the version. Try there: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4759f4ffa4363664f8697ca00ad6320e

Comment: Thanks FLYFLU. The query now runs without an error, but when I added new rows to the schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9139de/1) I found that the lastBooking column always displays the same date because the new JOIN with ctRequests is not limited to the userID of the original ctRequests. I tried fully qualifying all fields to make the connection, but then [the error comes back](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9139de/6)

Comment: Hi @Akina. I am running on MariaDB-10.4.15. I thought this was equivalent to mySQL 8.0 but when I change to that db version in your fiddle it doesn't recognise the keyword LATERAL

Comment: *I am running on MariaDB-10.4.15. I thought this was equivalent to mySQL 8.0* No. Forget about "equivalent to", now they're "similar to" only. Many years have passed, and the list of differences is now quite extensive.